# Saving nested attributes for profile in user model (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, profile, nested-attributes

I am building small page in RoR with Devise gem and got stuck.
When I want to save profile by nested attributes from user model there is an error and I can't get over it.

**User Model**

```
has_one :profile
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

**Profile Model**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**Edit user view (here I want to add profile information)**

```
<% resource.build_profile %>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, 
            :url => registration_path(resource_name), 
            :html => { :method => :put, :class => "custom" }) do |f| %>

(some fields for user)

    <%= f.fields_for :profile, :child_index => resource.id, 
                     :html => {:class => "custom"} do |profile| %>

        <%= profile.label :name %>
        <%= profile.text_field :name %>

        <%= profile.label :surname %>
        <%= profile.text_field :surname %>

    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit "Update my profile!" %>
<% end %>
```

**Error in browser**

```
Internal server error
```

**Error in terminal**

```
!! Unexpected error while processing request: expected Array (got Rack::Utils::KeySpaceConstrainedParams) for param `profile_attributes'
```

Thanks for help in advice :)

**EDIT**

That was stupid mistake... I had this part of code in my form:

```
                <%= profile.select :gender, %w[Male Female], {}, { :index => nil }%>
```

I deleted `{ :index => nil }`, now problem is gone :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are missing this in user.rb file:

```
attr_accessible :profile_attributes
```

Moreover, if it won't work, try to do

```
<% new_profile = resource.build_profile %>
...
<%= f.fields_for :profile, new_profile, ...
```